# Is there any way to get my while loop to work with a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

My problem is i am trying to write a fairly simple program where it asks the user if they would like to receive a compliment. The user can then enter a 'yes' or 'no'. I have a while loop that detects if the user says yes, then execute. However, it seems the code is just skipping right over it.

I've tried to get rid of .downcase and I have tried .upcase. It does work with integers, just not strings. I changed the == to 1 and set it as true and it executed perfectly fine. It just happens with string values, even when I use if statements.

Input:

```
compliment = Array.new
compliment[0] = "You look absolutely stunning right now!"
compliment[1] = "It's always a blast to hang out with you!"


print "Do you want a compliment?"
wantcompliment = gets.to_s
size = compliment.size

while (wantcompliment.downcase == 'yes')
  x = rand(size)
  xplusone = x + 1
  puts compliment[x]
  puts ''
  puts "You got compliment " + xplusone.to_s + " out of " + size.to_s
  print "Would you like another compliment?"
  wantcompliment = gets.to_s
end
puts wantcompliment.downcase #Debug
```

Output:

```
C:\Ruby26-x64\bin\ruby.exe C:/Users/test/RubymineProjects/Project5/Compliment.rb
Do you want a compliment?Yes
yes

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: try `wantcompliment = gets.to_s.strip`, basically you should get rid of the line breaker.

Comment: @sam, here `gets` returns a string, so `.to_s` is of questionable value. `chomp` is normally used to remove only the newline; `strip` is for removing whitespace at both the beginning and the end of the string returned by `gets`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah, you are right, according to the code, It's better to get rid of those white space around the actual characters when comparing to "yes" string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a string returned by `gets` has a newline appended:

```
irb(main):002:0> gets
yes
=> "yes\n"
```

You can just use `gets.chomp` instead, this will remove that trailing `\n` char:

```
irb(main):003:0> gets.chomp
yes
=> "yes"
```